# Как взять путь на лету Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Всем привет. Есть Класс контроллера в котором методы есть записи, изменения, удаления и просмотра.

Нужно при записи взять, путь записи для последуюзщей генерации QR-coda.

Проблема в том что путь до записывания данных в базу  неизвестен, как это можно по другому написать.

Есть вид который ссылается на метод в контроллёре

```
    {!! Form::open (['route'=>['tasks.store']]) !!}

            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" name="title" value="{{old('title')}}" class="form-control">
                <br>
                <textarea name="descriptions" cols="30" rows="10" id="" class="form-control">{{old('descriptions')}}</textarea>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

---

Для генерации QR-coda использую вот этот пакет.
 "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~2"

```
 public function store (createTaskRequest $request) {

    QrCode::format('png')
          ->size('180')
          ->errorCorrection('H')
          ->encoding('UTF-8')
          ->generate(ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО ПОЛУЧИТЬ ПУТЬ, И ЗАПИСАТЬ ЕГО );

    Task::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
}
```

Comment: ? не понятно что вам нужно, вам нужно просто сохранить куда то QR кол и добавить эту строку в TASK? ну положите куда нибудь, например в `$path = public_path('tash_'. microtime().png); QrCode....->generate($path)`, а потом `$input = $request->all(); $input['path'] = $path; Task::create($input)`

Comment: что такое путь?